# Saving a contact group that was sent via email to my outlook contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

How do I save a contact group that was sent via to my email - to my outlook contacts?

Answer (score 10):

To solve, as stated above, double click the "Contact Card", which is the attachment in the email sent to you.

Next, select the "file" tab

Then, click the big, "move to folder" button - select "Copy to folder" and select "My Contacts".

Other clarification:  When attempting to use this method in a new message, however - We still have to select "contacts" from the drop-down menu, where if we create our own group, the name of the "contact group" will automatically fill itself in as you begin typing it in the "to" field.

Comment: Its amazing this isn't easier. +1

Answer (score 0):

If it came as an attachment, simply double click on it and it will open up a dialog. On the dialog, select `Save and Close` or you can modify it as required (such as what you wish to name this contact group) before saving it.

If it is in the an email field, just right-click on the contact group name and select `Add to Outlook Contacts.`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by double-clicking the contact card in the attachment, selecting the File tab, clicking on the big 'Move to Folder' button, selecting 'Copy to folder...', and then selecting my contacts folder.

Not really intuitive, but it worked for me.  I wasn't able to just open the contact group up and hit save as suggested below...although that's probably how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

All you do is left click on the distribution list in the email and drag it from the email to the contacts button and drop it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is sent from another users contact list simply double click the attachment to open it. Click on File in the top left hand corner, you will then see a square button which says 'Move to folder' click that and you will see 2 drop downs click the second one which says 'copy to folder' scroll down to contacts, click it then press save.

Make sure to double check it has gone into your contacts and it is ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

After DAYS of trying to figure this out. All I did that worked was just drag and drop the attachment down to the "people" tab.

Another way that does work is to double-click the attachment, go to File, Move to Folder, Copy to Folder, then scroll down to Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple contact groups in the email, click on one, then right click and "select all" ; then "copy" and finally move to the peoples tab and CTRL+V (Paste).

Answer (score 0):

I just double clicked the contact card attachment from the email and it opened the contact card in my address book. Once open I just clicked save and close up top on the left. Once I did that it automatically went back to the Home Screen of my Inbox and I checked my address book to make sure it was added and it was!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).